# Dúvida com SQL/PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
$qrysel = "select * from pack";
$ressel = mysqli_query($db, $qrysel);
$obj = mysqli_fetch_object($ressel);
```

No html tenho isso:

```
<?= $obj['pack_name']; ?>
```

Como eu poderia fazer para ele mostrar o valor de acordo com uma determinada id, sem usar o `WHILE` e sem colocar o `WHERE` na query...

É possível definir o `WHERE` diretamente no obj do html?

Tabela:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>item 1</td>
      <td>item 2</td>
      <td>item 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item 4</td>
      <td>item 5</td>
      <td>item 6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Se eu fosse utilizar o while ele iria repetir todos os TD seguidamente, eu preciso que ele seja exibido como esta acima.

Existem exatamente 6 registros nessa tabela.

Comment: Não tem como. Teria que usar o `where` ou no pior caso fazer um while e fazer a comparação registro a registro.

Comment: Tente falar mais sobre o que deseja fazer, podemos ajudar com outras ideias

Comment: Então, eu não posso usar o while por que vai da problema com a exibição, pois tenho que exibir 3 itens por linha em uma tabela.. com o while ele vai exibir todos seguidos.

Comment: Vai dar problema porque provavelmente você não tem experiencia em trabalhar HTML+PHP, se você explicar melhor o que já fez tenho certeza que tem como resolver.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta, da uma olhada se da pra entender o que eu preciso fazer..

Comment: use um foreach($ressel as $obj){if($obj['id']==1){echo"<td>$obj['nome']</td>";}else {echo "sem registro";}  }

Comment: @TulioVieira Não sei como montar a estrutura utilizando esse método, se puder fornecer algum exemplo por favor..

Comment: @TulioVieira Eita isso funcionou perfeitamente, não conhecia essa função.. Muito obrigado :D

Comment: @Wendler publiquei uma reposta mais detalhada ali que bom que te ajudei cara fico muito feliz se puder votar na minha publicação e marcar como resposta está correta agradeço!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

em primeiro lugar você faz a querry

```html
$qrysel = "select * from pack";
$ressel = mysqli_query($db, $qrysel);
$obj = mysqli_fetch_object($ressel);
```

depois monta a tabela

```html
                                <table>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                                <th>id</th>
                                                <th>nome</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <?php
                                                foreach($ressel as $obj){ ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                   <?php if($obj['id']==1){echo "<td>"  .$obj['id']. "</td>";} else{ echo"sem registro";}?>
                                                   <?php if($obj['id']==1){echo "<td>"  .$obj['nome']. "</td>";}else{echo"sem registro";}?>
                                                </tr>
                                        <?php     }                                ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

tenta fazer isso aqui creio que irá resolver o seu problema!

Comment: Show, funcionou certinho :)

Comment: fico feliz @Wendler qualquer coisa é so falar tmj!